# Confused about Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

In this kind of situation, is it theoretically possible for a ball to stop at the top of the track?
Because when I try to apply the circular motion formula it tells me that, since at the top there is gravity, $mg=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ even when velocity is least.
However when I apply energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2=mg(2R)$, the ball stopping at the top is definitely possible.

What am I missing here? Can the circular motion formula not be applied when $v$=0?

Comment: Is the ball connected to the track, or can it fall off the upper section of the loop if moving too slow?

Comment: It can fall off.

Answer (score 4):

At the top of the loop, the ball is on the underside of the track. It obviously cannot come to a stop there, as it will just fall off the track. The ball must maintain a minimum speed in order to maintain contact with the track during the upper half of the loop, or else it will fall.

The equations you're using apply to the case where an object just barely coasts through the top of the loop under gravity alone, feeling no force whatsoever from the track. In that situation, the centripetal acceleration comes entirely from gravity and not at all from the normal force from the track. The equation explicitly states this, that the centripetal force is equal to the force of gravity alone. Given a particular apparatus with a fixed loop radius, object mass, and strength of gravity, we are able to solve for the speed at which the object "floats" through the top of the loop.

Going the other way and starting with a fixed v gives a somewhat unusual situation where you're solving for mass, loop size, or gravity. You can see that if v=0, we must have either g=0, m=0, or R=0. The only way the ball can stop at the top of the loop is if there is no gravity, there is no mass for gravity to act upon, or if the loop is actually just flat ground and not really a loop at all. Each of these cases rather strains the conceptual space of what we could call "circular motion", as we're now talking about massless particles traversing infinitesimal hills under the force of non-existent gravity, while not actually moving at all. With v=0, there isn't any motion at all, circular or otherwise - you're trying to apply equations of circular motion to a case where nothing is moving.

Answer (score -1):

$mg$ is the force of gravity on the car at the top. Only if the car is in uniform circular motion is this the centripetal force ${mv^2 \over R}$. For the car at rest at the top use your energy formula to determine the initial speed $v_0$ at the bottom: $v_0 = 2 \sqrt {gR}$ .

To evaluate the speed at the bottom for the call to not fall off at the top is more complicated, but it turns out to be $v_0 = \sqrt {5gR}$.

Comment: $2\sqrt{gR}$? Don't you mean $\sqrt{2gR}$?

Comment: No, check the energy balance.

Comment: Both the results I provide are correct. The speed for the car at rest is from conservation of energy.  The speed to not fall off is more complicated to evaluate, it requires the normal force to not be zero; for example, see example 1.13 in  https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf.  I do not understand the down vote.

Comment: I didn’t down vote it

Comment: Thanks.  Just wondering if someone caught a problem that I should be aware of.